# How to query the warehouse's branch in SAP B1?

Tags: sql, sapb1

I'm new to SAP B1 (version 9.1) and I haven't found how can I do the following:

I'm trying to list all items in stock by branch but I don't know how to get the warehouse's branch. I read that a warehouse belongs to only one branch but  I don't see how it's done. I'm able to list all items in stock in all warehouses by issuing this query:

```
SELECT T1."WhsName", T2."ItemName", T0."OnHand" 
FROM OITW T0 INNER JOIN OWHS T1 ON T0."WhsCode"=T1."WhsCode"
             INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T0."ItemCode"=T2."ItemCode"
WHERE T0."OnHand" > 0
ORDER BY T1."WhsName" ASC, T0."OnHand" DESC;
```

No idea how to get the warehouse's branch. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be a relation in your database that has data for warehouse and branch. You have to use that to redo your query. If a warehouse only belongs to one branch then there should be a column in T1 that has the branch code or name.

Comment: It's what I thought but cannot find that column nor a table (which I think shouldn't exist) that holds the relationship. I think the relationship comes from a more obscure way.

Comment: How did you set up your branches in the Administration module?

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau I don't know, I'm just getting started and SAP is already initialized. Is this setup important?

Comment: I would think that by branch you mean each warehouse. Is this so?

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau Well, now I'm looking into other queries and I think a warehouse is treated as a branch, is this ok?

Comment: Yes, a warehouse is in a specific location and should be treated as a branch. Any more info/fields you need in your query?

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau I didn't know, I guess that should be enough then. Thanks.